# mod rewrite escape chars

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

simple question, my url is

```
www.site.com/page--3
```

I need the rewriterule to read "/page--3" as two different values.

I have this working: 
*RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2*

This gives me the values 'page' and '3' from *www.site.com/page/3.*

**how** do i get the rewriterule to read the '--' as a seperator for the values so that i can read the page and number values? Simply changing the / to -- does not work, does it need to be in some reg expression or escape value?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but assuming I do, this should work:

```
^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/|--)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

It will match both `www.site.com/page--3` and `www.site.com/page/3`. Note, though, that in difference from your original regex, `$2` will be the separator and the values you're looking for are in `$1` and `$3`.

Comment: thank you nikc,
that is what i needed, new to expressions but learning quickly.
I got the expression you gave me to work and just rewriting the rest of my rules to work along.

Comment: Nice that you got it working. If you're on a PC, I've found Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is quite invaluable when debugging regexes. (No affiliation.) One of the few reasons I still am on a PC :-)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])/$  index.php?page--$1

Comment: hi kanak

the url will be 
www.site.com/page--pagenumber
and then i'll take that format and get the vaules

so i need to figure out how to get the rewrite to give the the values correctly, so basically using your suggestion is going the wrong way from what i need.

Firstly how does one specify the -- as the separator in the rule?

Thank you for the response tho.